Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'Data' rather than 'Task<Data>' error in ASP.NET and Entity Framework
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> View(Guid id)
{
    var employee = await mvcDemoDbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    if(employee != null)
    {
        var viewModel = new UpdateEmployeeViewModel()
        {
            Id = employee.Id,
            Name = employee.Name,
            Email = employee.Email,
            Salary = employee.Salary,
            Department = employee.Department,
            DateOfBirth = employee.DateOfBirth
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

In this function, I am getting the error mentioned in the title.
How to solve this issue?
When I am using
return await View(viewModel);

instead of
return View(viewModel);

then the view isn't displayed. It's getting redirect to Index. But when I am trying to use return View();, it shows the view but not with expected results.
Here is the markup for the view.cshtml file:
@model ASPNETMVCCRUD.Models.UpdateEmployeeViewModel

@{
}
<h1> Update Employee Information</h1>
<form method="post" action="View" class="mt-5">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Id</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Id" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" asp-for="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Salary</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Salary">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" asp-for="DateOfBirth">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Department</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Department">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>


Your View method is decorated with [HttpGet] attribute and needs a Guid parameter. How are you calling this Get View method? //View/{Guid}?

I'd avoid naming your method "View", use something like "Detail" so "/Employee/Detail/xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx" The View() method that should be called is the Controller's base View(object) to tell the render engine to compose the HTML with the provided viewmodel. This method is not async, but ASP.Net seems to be resolving your controller action based on the name and expecting an await since your method is named "View".
To keep the "View" route name would also probably work with:
return base.View(viewModel); 

... or you could name the method "Detail" but set the route explicitly to map to "/View".
[HttpGet]
[Route("View/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ViewDetail(Guid id)    

